# Using Semi-circle find side of triangle

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

The figure below above shown a bicycle path. If semicircular portion $ABC$ is $100$ $\pi$ and $CD$ is $100$$ft$ then what is $AD$?

[image: a busy cat](') ![two muppets]

I have tried to find the diamenter of the circle and the Pythagorean, I am not able figure out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter is $\pi$:
$$\frac{\text{circumference}}{\text{diameter}}=\pi.$$The length of the semicircle arc is **half** the circumference of what would be the full circle. Thus, 
$$\frac{\text{semicircle}}{\text{diameter}}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\text{circumference}}{\text{diameter}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\text{circumference}}{\text{diameter}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Using that $\text{semicircle}=100\pi$, solve for the length of the diameter of the circle. Note that this is the same as the length of the line segment $AC$. Lastly, now apply the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: diameter = 100 /D ?

Comment: Because $\text{semicircle}=100\pi$, we have $$\frac{\text{semicircle}}{\text{diameter}}=\frac{100\pi}{\text{diameter}}.$$
We know that this has to equal $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Solving
$$\frac{100\pi}{\text{diameter}}=\frac{\pi}{2},$$
we get
$$2\cdot 100\pi=\pi\cdot \text{diameter}$$
so that
$$\text{diameter}=200.$$

Comment: Final Answer is AD = 100

Comment: No, that's not correct. The Pythagorean theorem tells you
$$(AD)^2+(CD)^2=(AC)^2.$$
You now know that $AC=200$, and $CD=100$. Solve for $AD$.

Comment: 100 Sqrt of 3 final answer

Comment: Yup, that's right.
$$\fbox{$AD=100\sqrt{3}$}$$